# Delete all tables that don't contain certain strings VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying without success to delete all tables within Word document that dont contain some strings.

My current code is:

```
Sub DeleteTablesIf()
    Dim t As Table
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        If t not contains  "A" or  "B"  "C" then
         t.Delete
        End if 
    Next
End Sub
```

But I don't know how to check if the string "A" or "B" or "C" are present within each table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub DeleteTablesIf()
    Dim t As Table, i As Long, txt As String

    'loop backwards when deleting
    For i = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
            txt = .Range.Text
            If Instr(txt, "A") = 0 And  Instr(txt, "B") = 0 And _
                                        Instr(txt, "C") = 0 Then 
                .Delete
            End if 
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```